# display tag column as radio button

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, radio-button, displaytag

I have been having a problem getting the value associated with the radio button which is a column in the table. Instead of returning the actual `conferenceid`, it instead returning me `${conf.conferenceid}` text to the object `selectedConference`. Can someone help me what am I doing wrong here. By the way this code was working on Glassfish, recently migrated to JBoss and not working on it. Below is the html code :

```jsp
<display:table id="conf" name="conferences" requestURI="perConfSearchAction.action" pagesize="10">
    <display:column>
        <input type="radio" name="selectedConference" value="${conf.conferenceId}" onclick="getValue()"/>
    </display:column>
    <display:column property="userName" title="Moderator" sortable="true" />
    <display:column property="passcode" title="Public Pin" sortable="true" />
    <display:column property="moderatorPin" title="Moderator Pin" sortable="true" />                                
    <display:column property="confStartDate" title="Start Date" sortable="true" />                                                                
    <display:column property="confStartTime" title="Start Time" sortable="true" />                                
    <display:column property="confEndDate" title="End Date" sortable="true" />                                
    <display:column property="confEndTime" title="End Time" sortable="true" />                                
    <display:column property="confName" title="Subscription" sortable="true" />
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```jsp
<display:table id="conf" name="conferences" requestURI="perConfSearchAction.action" pagesize="10" uid="row">
  <display:column>
     <input type="radio" name="selectedConference" value="<s:property value='%{#attr.row.id}'/>"/>
  </display:column>
</display:table>
```